# Use $\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{1}{1 + \cos x + \sin x}dx = \ln 2$ to find $\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{x}{1 + \cos x + \sin x}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, definite-integrals, trigonometric-integrals

I am a PhD student studying analytic number theory, but a high school student showed me this integration problem and I couldn't quite crack it. I am wondering if anyone on here has some thoughts. The question is:

By using the fact that $$\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{1}{1 + \cos x + \sin x}dx = \ln 2 $$

compute
$$\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{x}{1 + \cos x + \sin x}dx$$

Of course, stick to tools that would be available to a first-year calculus student.

Comment: The substitution $t=\pi/2-x$ enables you to calculate the given integral from an equation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint:** Deal with the second integral using the substitution $x=\frac\pi2-y$ and $\mathrm dx=-\mathrm dy$.

Comment: ahh yep. got it. thanks man.

Answer (score 0):

$$I=\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}\frac{x}{1+\sin x+\cos x}dx$$
Let $x\to\frac{\pi}{2}-x$,then $$I=\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}\frac{\frac{\pi}{2}-x}{1+\cos x+\sin x}dx=\frac{\pi}{2}\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}\frac{dx}{1+\sin x+\cos x}-I$$
So$$I=\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{\pi}{2}\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}\frac{dx}{1+\sin x+\cos x}dx=\frac{\pi}{4}\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}\frac{dx}{1+\sin x+\cos x}$$
Let $\tan\frac{x}{2}=t\Longleftrightarrow x=2\arctan t$,$dx=\frac{2}{1+t^2}dt$,then
$$I=\frac{\pi}{4}\int_0^1\frac{2dt}{1+t^2+2t+1-t^2}=\frac{\pi}{4}\int_0^1\frac{2dt}{2+2t}=\frac{\pi}{4}\ln(1+t)\Big|_0^1=\frac{\pi\ln2}{4}$$
Notice: If $$F(a,b)=F(b,a)$$
then$$\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}xF(\sin x,\cos x)dx=\frac{\pi}{4}\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}F(\sin x,\cos x)dx$$